# Best and current tools and programming languages to use in building a web site that does engineering calculations and graph outputs

Tags: java, php, python, django, matplotlib

I have written a Python application that takes about 4 numbers from the user and does some calculations with it. The final result is displayed on a matplotlib graph. Now, I would like to take this application and put it on a web site. I want to have users sign up for a yearly subscription, do their calculations and print the results to a PDF to be saved on their computer. Because I know Python (but just a beginner at that), I tried to learn Django, but I hit many road blocks with Python version management, getting bunch of error messages that I could not debug. My question to you is what current tools and programming language would you recommend (Java, PHP, HTML, others). I am willing to learn and try anything. I'd rather be able to look at others' code to understand what they did and how they did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to build a large complex application before learning the basics. Python is fine for a server side language but you will need to get a good understanding of HTML, CSS and Javascript to pull pretty much anything of value off when it comes to the web. Take a look at sides like [Team Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/), [Code School](http://codeschool.com) or [Code Academy](http://codeacademy.com). They all have great courses to give you some more knowledge around not only HTML, CSS and JS but how to leverage those technologies into a system like explained above. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I will now check these out.